# How to get Billing details including usage details and tax

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-billing-api

I want to get Billing Details including Usage details and tax info ( cost including tax ). I used  GET [https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-10-01](https://management.azure.com/%7Bscope%7D/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-10-01)  this API but I am not able to get details about tax.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK currently the feature to get billing usage along with tax details is not supported.

[This](https://feedback.azure.com/) UserVoice / feedback forum is the communication channel for new features and idea's related to Azure.

I see [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/37353724-make-azure-billing-more-customizable) / [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906772-cost-management/suggestions/37715776-add-tax-and-credits-to-the-daily-billing-export) related feature requests already being raised. So I recommend you to upvote it and other features that are of interest. In general, Azure feature team would check feasibility of the feature request, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.